# How to un-swizzle a method in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

It's clear how to swizzle a method, but how do you cancel that and revert to original?

On iOS 8 it seams that you can simply call the swizzle method again and it changes back to the original, but on iOS 7 it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I needed the swizzling to be toggleable. The swizzle code is within a Framework that lets a parent app launch or exit our module, and I only wanted swizzling when the module was open.  I added a flag (in my case a BOOL in another class) which the swizzled method first checks; if it's off then it immediately calls the original method and exits, and if on then it proceeds with the custom code.
Flipping the switch once only would in effect undo the swizzle.